# Shared folders and permissions (windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, security, permissions, logging, group-policy

I am creating a few files for particular users and groups with limited permissions, basically read and execute.

So, its works just fine.

The problem is that when a user is trying to delete a file there is a popup window where it asks him for admin password. Is it possible instead of this window, to appear something else , like "access denied" , or "not enough privileges" ? Just a windows built in warning, and not a password prompt for Admin pass.

Answer (score 2):

Go to Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network and Sharing Center\Advanced sharing settings

Or type "*Advanced sharing settings*" in the start menu and open the link

Then, scroll down to "*HomeGroup Connections" and select "Allow Windows to manage homegroup connections (recommended)*"

The option below that is what makes Windows ask for a password when trying to execute a command outside of ones permissions range.

Comment: That one option is already selected by default. So its not this.

Comment: Dude, you don't understand the problem. I just don't want this windows 7  to give a password prompt to simple users for files that aren't for them , just an error message, access denied or something.